# calling a virtual method from constructor by qualified name

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, virtual-functions

I know that calling virtual methods from constructors should be avoided. But is following example still such case? I.e. is it OK to call virtual function by qualified name selecting exact override to call?

```
struct base {
    virtual void foo( ) = 0;
};

struct derived : base {

    derived( ) {
        // IMHO derived's override gets called no matter what, right?
        this->derived::foo( );
    }

    void foo( ) override {
        // derived does something
    }

};

struct eventual_more_derived : derived {

    void foo( ) override {
        // eventual_more_derived may do something different
    }

};
```

Comment: All cases of calling a virtual function should be avoided in in my opinion

Comment: "OK" in the sense of "well-defined" or in the sense of "good, maintainable, easy-to-understand code"?

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I was thinking more about "well-defined" sense, it could have its use case

Comment: anyway @Mat pointed me to similar question which I didn't find before and which clarifies that such thing is usable, thank you all :-)